# What is meant by aided students in College Scorecard?

Tags: collegescorecard

For example: Aided students with family incomes between $48,001-$75,000 in nominal dollars  student share_middleincome.48001_75000  float   INC_PCT_M2

Is this

- (a) receiving federal aid?
- (b) receiving any federal or institutional aid?
- (c) Pell grant recipients
- (d)???

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: it's Title IV aid-receiving students.

Comment: Please add some more info so that the rest of the world understands what this is about...